# NextJS + Apollo + i18n - unexpected error

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo, react-i18next

The client I am working with at the moment has requested I build a SSR React app which includes i18n. To solve this problem I tried to use NextJS and i18Next.

I managed to get react and apollo linked up without issue but when I tried to connect next + i18n I keep getting a very unhelpful 'an unexpected error' occured, error.

Inspecting the console I also see the following:

```
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.inherits (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:36080:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:30216:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:30440:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/manifest.js:714:31)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/manifest.js:117:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:28246:12)
    at Object.module.exports.exports.byteLength (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:28507:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/manifest.js:714:31)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/manifest.js:117:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1515592576452/page/index.js:24501:18)
```

Also this warning but i'm not sure it's related

```
warning.js?e7f4ca8:33 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
```

I've also noticed that in ./libs/withData.js there is the following line:

`enter code here`static displayName = `WithData(${getComponentDisplayName(
      ComposedComponent
    )})`

My editor flags that as an invalid token but this code came from the [nextjs example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib/withData.js) and there is no issue on that repo which suggests it's a typo.

I've included all the code that pertains to this issue in the following codepen project.

https://codepen.io/foxleigh81/project/editor/DnYJWB

Answer (score 0):

OK I've sort of worked it out.

In a nutshell. I was thinking about this all wrong. I was thinking I was adding next to my react app, whereas the reality is more like I'm putting my react app inside next. I took it apart and rebuilt it from scratch, assembling the examples on the [nextjs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js) repo and it all worked.

Comment: How did you solve the `unexpected token =` in `withData.js`?

Comment: Technically I didn't. I took the entire app apart and rebuilt it using the examples in the repo and it worked. Now NextJS 5 is out though I'd be willing to bet that there is an even easier way.